# Single CSS from appasset.php per page in yii2

Tags: javascript, css, yii2

I am using the `yii2` framework and the following code in `appasset.php`:

```
public $basePath = '@webroot'; 
public $baseUrl = '@web'; 
public $css = [ 'css/site.css', 'css/country.css', 'css/admin/one.css', 'css/fg/two.css' ]; 
public $js = [ ]; 
public $depends = [ 'yii\web\YiiAsset', 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset', ];
```

My page pulls in all of the CSS files listed, but I only want `one.css` in this page, and to use the other CSS files in other pages.

How can I prevent these other CSS files from appearing in this page? Or - is it possible to create a new `appasset.php` file for a single `php` page?

Comment: Clarifying question & title, and improving readability.

Answer (score 1):

Each specific situation should have its own AssetBundle. 
You just create as many as you need and include them in the relevant view file:

Existing one:

```
class AppAssets extends \yii\web\AssetBundle 
{ 
   public $basePath = '@webroot'; 
   public $baseUrl = '@web';
   public $css = ['css/site.css', 'css/country.css', 'css/fg/two.css'];
   ...
}
```

Additional one:

```
class AdminAssetBundle extends \yii\web\AssetBundle 
{ 
   public $basePath = '@webroot'; 
   public $baseUrl = '@web';
   public $css = ['css/admin/one.css'];
   public $depends = ['AppAssets'],
}
```

(Please add namespaces where necessary, I left those out)

As said: Then just include the one you need in the view that is relevant.
ie. in your admin views you add: `AdminAsset::register($this);`

Because of the `depends`, those views will automatically include your `AppAssets` bundle.

If your `AppAssets` is the one from the yii app distribution (added by default), it is probably already being registered in the `/views/layouts/main.php`-file.

That means that it is not required to be defined as a dependency. 
I do consider it a good practice to keep the dependencies clear (if your admin one.css file actually depends on the ones from `AppAssets`, if not remove the `$depends` alltogether).

Yii is smart enough to only include each asset bundle only once anyway.